# OnClickListener doesn't works in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener, navigation-drawer

As I am developing an app,where it has a Navigation Drawer it works perfectly but where i placed two images view where they doesn't fire the onClickListener..please tell me how to implement the onclciklistener to work like edit and delete operations...[image]
and the

rowlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relative">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the mainActivity.java

```
/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                final long id) {
            text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello" + text, 3000)
                    .show();
            selectItem(position);
            positn = position;
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(text);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + text,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ImageView edit_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            edit_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked", 3000)
                            .show();

                }
            });

            if (text.equals("add new item")) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                input.setHeight(100);
                input.setWidth(340);
                input.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

                input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

                builder2.setMessage("Press OK or Cancel");
                builder2.setView(input);

                builder2.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                userinput = input.getText().toString();

                                // int length2 = userinput.length();
                                // String string23 = Integer.toString(length2);
                                // Log.d("length of userinput", string23);

                                listItems.add(userinput);

                                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label,
                                        listItems);
                                mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
                                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                                String counter = "0";
                                Log.v("id", "" + id);
                                Log.v("name", "" + userinput);
                                Log.v("value", "" + counter);

                                database1.open();
                                long insertid;

                                insertid = database1.Insertvalues(id1,
                                        userinput, counter);
                                // String string2 = Integer.toString((int)
                                // insertid);
                                // Log.d("values inserted", string2);
                                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" +
                                // insertid, 3000).show();

                            }

                        });

                builder2.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                            }

                        });

                builder2.show();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: i have implemented but it doesn't fires the onclickListener..

Comment: ImageView edit_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   edit_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked", 3000)
       .show();

    }
   });

Comment: Make method like myClick(View v) and apply this in xml for your images

Comment: i have set the onclicklistener in the DrawerItemClickListener..

Comment: Show us the code. Not -just- the XML.

Comment: @Guardanis  posted the code....

Comment: post the xml for drawer and code where you add listener

Comment: drawer_list_item.xml    :--<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listitem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine.

But the problem is you set **onClick** for **ImageView** after click to **ListItem**

You have to click to **ListItem**, after that, you can click to **ImageView**.

Please move this code to outside of **onItemClick**

```
ImageView edit_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            edit_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked", 3000)
                            .show();

                }
 });
```

Comment: Which code? Please move this question to chat window. I think. I can help you.

Comment: This link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50189/22563246-navigation-drawer I am waiting for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom array adapter and set it to the drawer list view. On the custom adapter getView() when you inflate the item layout, find the image view and set the listener( this will be the inner child items)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position , View contentView , ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row  = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);

    ImageView imageView2  = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id. imageView2);
    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // handle the edit click here
        }
    });

   ImageView imageView1  = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id. imageView1);
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // handle the delete click here
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use a custom adapter as the inner child views should be of different instance to handler click as separate item.